# Android videoview - Error for internal storage URI

Tags: java, android

I am a beginner at Android programming and I had a doubt to be clarified.
I tried out a tutorial on VideoView in Android and observed that,
When the specified URI string is "http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/AndroidCommercial.3gp", the program works.
I tried replacing the URI string with the location of a video present in the phone's internal storage (/storage/emulated/0/Movies/test.mp4) and the program produced the error `java.io.IOException: setDataSource failed`.
My question is what does the error signify and why does it occur ? since both the URI string's do specify the video to be played.

(Note: I followed [this tutorial](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-video-streaming-videoview-tutorial/))

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to get a video from gallery:

```
// in onCreate method    
Intent getVid= new Intent();
                            getVid.setType("video/*");
                            getVid.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(getVid, "Select a video" ),


@Override
            protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                } if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                    String videoUrl = data.getData().toString();
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this , videoViewActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra("vid" , videoUrl);
                    startActivity(i);

                }
```

in videoViewActivity type this code in onCreate method after initializing videoView :

```
String path = getIntent().getStringExtra("vid");
videoView.setVideoPath(path);
videoView.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because of your Uri. When you use `Uri.parse("/blabla")` it's not validating that path, is it really exist or not. And in your case you need to give something like "file:///storage/emulated/0/Movies/test.mp4". Or your app don't have file permission, you need to add a permission check first.

Comment: I tried Akash Pal's answer given below and it worked. So it could not have been permissions but the URI itself, but, it still doesn't make sense. How did it validate the path of a video stored on the internal storage of the device via `getExternalStorageDirectory` which clearly states path retrieval of something stored on external storage?